# Why does a printf() allow this double to be passed by pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, visual-studio-2008

A pair of `printf()` debugging statements reveals that a pointer to a double that I am passing is, when dereferenced at the receiving end, coming out as a different value — but only under Microsoft Visual Studio (version 9.0). The steps are quite simple:

```
    double rho=0;       /* distance from the Earth */
    /* ... */
    for (pass = 0; pass < 2; pass++) {
        /* ... */
        rho = sqrt(rsn*rsn+rp*rp-2*rsn*rp*cpsi*cos(ll));
        printf("\nrho from sqrt(): %f\n", rho);
        /* ... */
    }
    /* ... */
    cir_sky (np, lpd, psi, rp, &rho, lam, bet, lsn, rsn, op);
    /* ... */
}
/* ... */
static void
cir_sky (
/* ... */
double *rho,        /* dist from earth: in as geo, back as geo or topo */
/* ... */)
{
    /* ... */
    printf("\nDEBUG1: *rho=%f\n", *rho);
```

The entire C file is here:

https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/pyephem/blob/9cd81a8a7624b447429b6fd8fe9ee0d324991c3f/libastro-3.7.7/circum.c#L366

I would have expected that the value displayed in the first `printf()` would be the same as that displayed by the second, since passing a pointer to a double should not result in a different value. And under GCC they are, in fact, always the same value. Under Visual Studio 32-bit compilation they are always the same. But when this code is compiled with Visual Studio under a 64-bit architecture, the two double values are different!

https://ci.appveyor.com/project/brandon-rhodes/pyephem/build/1.0.18/job/4xu7abnl9vx3n770#L573

```
rho from sqrt(): 0.029624

DEBUG1: *rho=0.000171
```

This is disconcerting. I wondered: does the code between where `rho` is computed and where the pointer is finally passed somehow destroy the value by bad pointer arithmetic? So I added one last `printf()`, right above the  `cir_sky()` call, to see if the value has already been altered by that point or whether it is altered in the course of the call itself:

```
    printf("\nrho about to be sent: %f\n", rho);
    cir_sky (np, lpd, psi, rp, &rho, lam, bet, lsn, rsn, op);
```

Here is that line in the context of the whole file:

https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/pyephem/blob/28ba4bee9ec84f58cfffabeda87cc01e972c86f6/libastro-3.7.7/circum.c#L382

And guess what?

**Adding the `printf()` fixed the bug — the pointer passed to `rho` can now be dereferenced to the correct value!**

As can be seen here:

https://ci.appveyor.com/project/brandon-rhodes/pyephem/build/1.0.19/job/s3nh90sk88cpn2ee#L567

```
rho from sqrt(): 0.029624

rho about to be sent: 0.029624

DEBUG1: *rho=0.029624
```

I am mystified.

What edge case of the C standard am I running into here? Why does merely using the value `rho` in the top-level scope of this function force the Microsoft compiler to correctly preserve its value? Is the problem that `rho` is both set and used inside of a block, and Visual Studio does not deign to preserve its value outside of that block because of a quirk of the C standard that I have never quite internalized?

You can see the entire build output at the AppVeyor link above. The particular compilation step for this C file, in case the problem might be how Visual Studio is invoked or the compile options, is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ilibastro-3.7.7 -IC:\Python27-x64\include -IC:\Python27-x64\PC /Tclibastro-3.7.7\circum.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libastro-3.7.7\circum.obj
circum.c
libastro-3.7.7\circum.c(126) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data 
libastro-3.7.7\circum.c(127) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
libastro-3.7.7\circum.c(139) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data 
libastro-3.7.7\circum.c(140) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data 
libastro-3.7.7\circum.c(295) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data 
libastro-3.7.7\circum.c(296) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
libastro-3.7.7\circum.c(729) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data 
libastro-3.7.7\circum.c(730) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
```

None of those warnings are, from what I can see, for code involved in this particular puzzle — and even if they were, all they would signify is that a float value might become less precise (from about 15 digits of decimal precision to 7), not that it could change completely.

Here, again, are the outputs of the two compilation-and-test runs, the first of which failed and the second of which — because of the `printf()`? — succeeded:

https://ci.appveyor.com/project/brandon-rhodes/pyephem/build/1.0.18/job/4xu7abnl9vx3n770

https://ci.appveyor.com/project/brandon-rhodes/pyephem/build/1.0.19/job/s3nh90sk88cpn2ee

Both are for exactly the same architecture, according to AppVeyor:

```
Environment: PYTHON=C:\Python27-x64, PYTHON_VERSION=2.7.x, PYTHON_ARCH=64, WINDOWS_SDK_VERSION=v7.0
```

Comment: Why did you tag this with `python`?

Comment: Because it is happening while compiling a C extension, but since the error is occurring right between one `printf` and other in C code that does not call Python, I have removed the tag — and am hoping that the Python library’s presence really truly has nothing to do with the problem!

Comment: Can you replace the ellipsis with `/* ... */` or something similar, or just remove them altogether? It's making the code really hard to read.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Done.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Could there be a memory corruption somewhere in your code? Memory corruptions commonly cause non-determinstic behaviours like this. Might be worth running it through something like valgrind.

Comment: @AlanAu — This code is single threaded, and the only other pointer operation of any sort that I see between the two `printf()` calls is `&lam` which simply creates a second pointer to an automatic sitting on the stack next to `rho` itself — so even if all pointers and pointer operations elsewhere in the code were broken and corrupting memory, I think that they would simply not receive any opportunity to change the value of `rho`?

Comment: Odd.  I notice that `rho` was only accessed inside a `for` loop before, so maybe there’s a buggy optimization about whether it’s in a register or memory—while this isn’t a solution you’d use in production code, does declaring it `volatile` and removing the `printf` also solve the problem?  Does adding the line outside the `for` loop, `rho += 0.0;` solve it?

Comment: @Lorehead — `rho` is also accessed a few lines farther down, where magnitude is calculated, so it still has to be available until close to the end of the function’s lifespan.

Comment: @user3386109 — Alas, I lack access to a Windows platform except through CI services like AppVeyor, and the number of round-trips to the build service to construct a minimal example is nearly prohibitive.

Comment: Okay.  I had a conjecture that the optimizer wasn’t realizing that passing `&rho` is an access; does any access to `rho` between initialization and the call fix the problem?

Comment: Another thought. Perhaps you are linking against a 32-bit libc?

Comment: Is there anyway to reduce the size of the code and remove the linkage to python stuff and still reproduce this problem?

Comment: My guess is that there is some dereferenced pointer being modified, which has unpredictable effects on surrounding memory. With no `printf`, this modification affects `rho`. With `printf`, this modification affects the memory allocated for printing, and doesn't affect rho.

Comment: Double check that the types of the parameters defined in `cir_sky` match up correctly with the types of the variables you are passing in the call to it.

Comment: Can you please also print out the address of `rho` outside and inside cir_sky? It could be a memory alignment issue.

Answer (score 1):

My quick look at this code didn't come up with anything that stands out as wrong or problematic. But, when a `printf` solves the problem, that means there is some non-determinism present. Let's analyze possible causes:

1. Concurrency - data races: most common, but you say it's single threaded.
2. Uninitialized memory: `rho` is initialized here, but, maybe something somewhere else isn't and it's messing things up. I'd run valgrind (on Linux) and AdressSanitizer and other sanitizers (should be available on clang and gcc for Windows, too) to see if they come up with something.
3. Wild pointers and other out-of-bounds access: nothing in the code we see here, but it's calling other functions. Again, run valgrind and sanitizers.
4. If previous steps come up short, the next most probable candidate is a MSVC bug. MSVC is notorious for messing up things in some complex code, and this is somewhat complex. Many times have I rearranged code just to make MSVC happy. Sometimes turning off optimization helps, sometimes it doesn't. Ditto for trying out different compiler options. Sometimes there is an update/patch that helps, sometimes there isn't. Ditto for the next version of MSVC. I'd suggest looking at disassembler in the debugger, but you say you don't have access to a Windows machine. The best bet here would be to try and simplify the code - make functions smaller, cut down number of arguments.
5. There are other possible causes. For example, maybe the stack got messed up for some reason - maybe when interacting with Python runtime. Try to build & run it as "regular" C code, rather than a Python extension. Eliminate calls to other functions (if it messes up with calculations, never mind, you're just trying to find out the problem).

In any case, I recommend you get your hands on a Windows machine and debug it. That's the best way to get to the bottom of such problems, in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an effect of (faulty) optimization?

Turn off any optimization (DEBUG?) and see if you get the same effect.

Of course, if you find it is the optimizer then you are up the crick and can only do something to fool it e.g. a sprintf that does nothing.

Also, you printf's could also print out the pointer ("%16x", (long) &rho)  not that I think it is incorrect but just as a sanity clause in case we are missing summat.  Also, the result of most doubles with random bits usually ends up in the E+/-317 range so the 0.000171 result is a little too reasonable to be completely suspect.

Comment: These are all good suggestions but is not really an answer to the question. Better placed as comments.

Comment: ya well i don't have 50r yet so this is the best I can do.

Comment: @brian_carcich Fair enough. But the better thing to do is to get more rep points and not comment until you do. The rules are there for a reason. Working around the rules by posting non-answer answers isn't really something that should be done.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable answer to try and track down the issue. If the problem can be reproduced with a debug build, then if VS's debugger includes a watch point type break, that could be used to check for any writes to rho, to see what is corrupting it.